# Implementing Tree structures in IPad

Tags: ios, ipad, tree

How to implement a tree structure in iPad, tree structure which contain parent & child nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use tableview for doing this.

Setting the cell indentationLevel property to denote the tree structure. And, it's possible to expand/collapse "tree branches" if you write code to manipulate the cell heights (can be set to zero).

Or else try using a UITableview with UINavigation controller instead.

Answer (score 0):

The apple-y way of doing this is to drill into a new list leaving a button to go back to its parent. This is done through `UINavigationController`. If your dead-set on indenting then as KingofBliss says change the cell indentationLevel